# Action not found in Mailer preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm having a weird issue with my TransactionMailer Preview.
I have the file `test/mailers/previews/transaction_mailer_preview.rb` looking good.

When i access `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/` i can see the TransactionMailer preview and all of its actions and the mailer preview is rendered correctly.

However, as soon as i refresh, the mailer disappears from the list and the action cannot be found. The issue is fixed if i restart the server, but only for one time, then disappears again!

Any idea? Rails 5.2 and MiniTest standard.

Comment: Did you have the `config.action_mailer.preview_path` configured to your `development` environment?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: problem solved by removing the Devise mailer preview. Not sure what the real problem was though!

Comment: The same just happened to me. I investigated for multiple hours and your comment fixed it for me. Somehow removing the Devise Mailer Preview fixed the issue for me. I would of course love to have the preview for my Devise mails so I will keep investigating :)

Answer (score 3):

For me this issue came up because I defined the Devise Mailer Preview in the file `devise_mailer_preview.rb` like this:

`class Devise::MailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview`

in Rails 5 the convention though seems to use:

`class DeviseMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview`

This fixes the issue of disappearing Mailer Previews after editing.

Comment: Great, thanks. Also had to change `DeviseMailer.confirmation_instructions(…)` to  `Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(…)` etc., to get Devise Mailer previews to work again.